# Setting different keys for switching between different keyboard layouts, how can be implemented in Windows?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, keyboard-layout

Using the tool AutoHotKey I could set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key for switching keyboard layouts ([here](https://superuser.com/a/431302/315125)). But I still want to set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> for Layout_1 and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> or backtick <kbd>`</kbd> for Layout_2.

Is it possible to set different combination of keys for different layouts in windows?

<kbd>Capslock</kbd> --> 1st Layout

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> --> 2nd Layout

Comment: You can write two batch scripts that select one of the two layouts ([instructions and example](https://superuser.com/questions/395818/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-via-command-line-cmd-exe-on-windows-xp-7) and attach each of those scripts tot a key using AutoHotKey.

Comment: simple solution is to set some combo e.g. Alt+Shift+1 via keyboard setup first and then bind it with Autohotkey to Capslock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system it's the Alt+Shift combination that [changes the keyboard language](https://ccm.net/faq/3844-keyboard-shortcut-to-change-language) and this works:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff ; Forces the CapsLock key to stay off permanently

; Replace 0x0409 and 0x1407 with the Language identifier of your keyboard languages described here:
; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings

Capslock:: ; 1st Layout
If !(GetKeyboardLanguage(WinActive("A")) = 0x0409) ; English ; "!" means "NOT"
    SendInput, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
return

+CapsLock:: ; 2nd Layout
If !(GetKeyboardLanguage(WinActive("A")) = 0x1407) ; German
    SendInput, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
return

; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/116538-detect-which-language-is-currently-on/#entry672236   
GetKeyboardLanguage(_hWnd=0){
    if !_hWnd
        ThreadId=0
    else
        if !ThreadId := DllCall("user32.dll\GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", _hWnd, "UInt", 0, "UInt")
            return false    
    if !KBLayout := DllCall("user32.dll\GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadId, "UInt")
        return false    
    return KBLayout & 0xFFFF
}
```