# How to change active keyboard layout (not the list of enabled layouts) via command-line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-layout

I have a list of keyboard layouts *already configured* (for instance, `us`, `dv`, and `ru`); I switch between them with Win+Space, and the list changes occasionally. However, I have a need to **switch to** one of these configured layouts (without modifying the list) programmatically.

How can this be done from the command-line? (CMD would be preferred, though a PowerShell or VBScript solution would be acceptable if it's not possible though CMD.)

This is **not** a duplicate of [How to change keyboard layout via command line cmd.exe on Windows XP/7?](https://superuser.com/q/395818/165335), which Accepted an answer stating how to change *the list of* keyboard layouts. As per the title, I am asking in this question how to *change the keyboard layout* -- that is, the active one -- without modifying the list of enabled layouts.

Comment: My specific use-case is: I must always switch the layout to US-International before starting certain games, due to their keybinds; I don't like the inconvenience of having to remember to do so, or restart the game if I've neglected to do so.

Comment: Found this when searching for an answer to the same question. I eventually got the `Set-WinUserLanguageList` working well enough for my needs: although it sets the whole language list the first keyboard layout on the first language also gets active when running the script.